# The commutation relation between the square components of angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, quantum-measurements

So my question is as follows. I was reading about Angular Momentum from Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics and it is a well known fact that the components of angular momentum do not commute-
$$[L_x,L_y]=i\hbar L_z \qquad[L_y,L_z]=i\hbar L_x \qquad[L_z,L_x]=i\hbar L_y$$ and thus, states with definite values of angular momentum vector don't exist. But in one of the problems, he gave a commutation relation to prove which read- 
$$[L_x^2,L_y^2]=[L_y^2,L_z^2]=[L_z^2,L_x^2]=0$$

Even before trying to prove that, one question has been striking me again and again. Is it possible then to measure the "magnitudes" of x,y,z components of angular momentum?

For example, is it possible that if I measure the $L^2$ of some state as $14\hbar ^2$ (in the appropriate units) and $L_z$ as $3\hbar$, then can I since it is possible to calculate the square of $L_x$ and $L_y$, i.e. can I determine $|L_x|=\hbar$ and $|L_y|=2\hbar$ ? Is it possible then to calculate the angular momentum vector upto a sign indeterminacy?

Comment: $14\neq l(l+1)$ for integer *l* and suggested by your $L_z$ eigenvalue. Maybe this is at the root of your $|L_i|$ notational misconception. It is easiest to test drive your vision with Pauli matrices, that are easy to slug through.

Comment: Yeah. I made a mistake there. You can take m=3 and l=3 too. That would mean the total angular momentum is $12\hbar^2$. Then $L_z=3\hbar$ and you can take $L_x=\hbar$ and $L_y=\sqrt{2}\hbar$. 

But it still leaves the question of interpretation of $L_i^2$'s to be defined.

Comment: Actually, I am still trying to figure out what those 3x3 matrices are. I haven't ever dealt with spin states and so, it is taking some time to first understand them and then your answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_quantum_mechanics#Angular_momentum_as_the_generator_of_rotations

Comment: I do not belive that $[L_x^2,L^2_y]=0$, and   I can't see this excercise in my (early edition) copy of Griffiths.  Can you post an image of the actual problem as stated in your copy?

Answer (score 1):

Absorb $\hbar$ into the normalization of the *L* operators for simplicity. 
I will not detract from the delight on figuring out the "inspection" solution of your text's homework (anticommutator of an obvious commutator).

The crucial remark in your question is that, e.g. $L_z$ *does not commute* with $L_x^2$ and $L_y^2$, so it is not simultaneously diagonalizable with them, and your warped vision of the vector model of the atom does not cohere.

Rather than picking higher spins that prevent intuitive direct checking, pick the triplet (vector) representation of ordinary space, so *l* = 1,
$$ L_{x} = i\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{matrix}\right) , \quad
 L_{y} = i\left(\begin{matrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{matrix}\right) , \quad
 L_{z} = i\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{matrix}\right),
$$
hence
$$
L_x^2= \operatorname{diag}~ (0,1,1) , \qquad  
L_y^2= \operatorname{diag}~ (1,0,1) , \qquad 
L_z^2= \operatorname{diag}~ (1,1,0) , \qquad 
\vec L^2= \operatorname{diag}~ (2,2,2) , \qquad 
$$
the first three with eigenvalues 0 and 1, and the last one, the Casimir, with 1(1+1)=2; they share the evident eigenvectors, but assign differing eigenvalues to them, in general. This is something you already know, of course, but is useless to your vector model.

Now note *how* the eigenvectors of $L_z$ "snag" on $L_x^2$ and $L_y^2$ and fail to always be *their* eigenvectors. What you may be thinking of as dross phases are at the very center of the group structure you are considering.

For instance, confirm the maximal eigenvalue eigenvector of $L_z$, namely, $(1,i,0)^T/\sqrt{2}$, fails to be an eigenvector of $L_x^2$ and $L_y^2$ above.

Comment: I am very sorry but I am getting a little trouble understanding your notation. I don't exactly understand what you mean by the triplet reresentation. I am taking my first course in Quantum Mechanics so I just understand the basic wave mechanics. Sorry for the trouble, but can you explain it in a simpler way? Thanks.

Comment: Triplet rep means spin 1, so *l* =1. That is, 3-vectors being acted upon by the 3x3 matrices for ,,,  which I now inserted

Answer (score 0):

If you take the definitions of the operators, and do the derivatives, it is clear that the eigenvalue of the squared operator is not the square of the operator eingenvalue. There are 2 extra terms. Ex:

$L_zf = -i(x\partial_y - y\partial_x)f$
$L_z^2f = L_z L_zf = -(x^2\partial^2_y + y^2\partial^2_x - 2xy\partial_{xy} - x\partial_x - y\partial_y)f$

Answer (score 0):

Besides the basic facts about the angular momentum, there is a hidden classical mis-intuition here, that measuring the square of the quantity (or any other power) is the same as measuring the quantity itself, up to the respective transformation.

This is not the case neither in quantum mechanics, nor in classical probability:

**Classical probability**
In classical probability the average of the squared quantity is not just a square of the average. As an easy example one can take a normal distribution with zero mean and standard deviation $\sigma$:
$$w(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$
We readily obtain
$$\langle x\rangle = 0, \langle x^2 \rangle=\sigma^2\neq \langle x\rangle^2.$$

**Quantum case**
One could easily generalize the above example to quantum case by taking the ground state of a harmonic oscillator. An even simpler example is however linear momentum. A wave function
$$\psi(x)=e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}$$ corresponds to a state with definite energy (of non-relativistic particle), $E=\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}$, but the momentum expectation value is zero. This is despite the fact that the kinetic energy operator is proportional to the square of the momentum operator:
$$K=\frac{p^2}{2m}.$$

Comment: The momentum of that state isn't zero, it's just not well-defined. The momentum operator yields the state $\hat{p}\psi = k(e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx})$. Your point still stands though, a well-defined value for the square of an operator tells you almost nothing about the value of the operator.

Comment: @LukePritchett the expectation value of momentum is zero - I changed the wording accordingly. Thanks.